# Импорт товарного XML-фида в БД mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется товарный xml-фид Яндекс.Маркета.

```
 ...
    <categories>
    <category id="90401">Все товары</category>
    <category id="91284" parentId="90401">категория1</category>
    ...
    <category id="91285" parentId="90401">категория2</category>
    </categories>
    ...
    <offers>
     <offer id="123" available="true">
      <name>Букет из 9 подсолнухов</name>
      <categoryId>91284</categoryId>
      <picture>https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-mpic...</picture>
      <price>3780</price>
      <currencyId>RUB</currencyId>
      <url>https://market.yandex.ru/product--buket-iz-9-podsolnukhov...</url>
      <group_id>1445709647</group_id>
      <vendor>5 Цветов</vendor>
      <oldprice>5670</oldprice>
      <description>&lt;p&gt;Состав букета:&lt;br /&gt;Подсолнухи - 9 шт.&lt;br /&gt;Атласная лента.&lt;/p&gt;</description>
     </offer>
     <offer id="166" available="true">
      <name>Сборный букет Flawery коробки с цветами. розы желтые. ирисы. n96</name>
      <categoryId>91284</categoryId>
      <picture>https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-mpic/52214...</picture>
      <price>3330</price>
      <currencyId>RUB</currencyId>
      <url>https://market.yandex.ru/product--sbornyi-buket-fla...</url>
      <group_id>1661423424</group_id>
      <vendor>Flowerstorg</vendor>
      <description>Если вас интересуют оригинальные ...</description>
      <param name="&#x426;&#x432;&#x435;&#x442;">желтый/фиолетовый</param>
     </offer>
    </offers>
```

Ручная загрузка - пошаговое прохождение структуры файла (XMLReader + SimpleXMLElement) с выполнением INSERT-комманд для добавления в базу занимает неприлично много времени.

Каким образом можно быстро загружать подобные XML в базу?

LOAD DATA LOCAL XML не подходит для указанной структуты XML.

Первое что приходит в голову - предварительно подготовить xml к виду, пригодному для LOAD DATA заменой строк регулярными выражениями.

```
Например это:  <category id="91284" parentId="90401">категория1</category>

Заменить на это: <category><id>91284</id><name>категория2</name><parrentId>90401</parrentId></category>
```

А уже потом импортировать.

Но может быть уже есть какой-то более быстрый и эффективный способ для связки PHP+mySQL?

Comment: [LOAD XML Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/)

Comment: LOAD XML поддерживает структуру xml-а только трех типов. Ни под один из них мой пример не подходит. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-xml.html

Comment: Это какой же фрагмент в показанном XML не соответствует ни одному из трёх поддерживаемых?

Comment: id и parentId как вытаскивать из таких XML-ов? они параметрами заданы.

Comment: и еще каждая запись offer имеет разный набор полей (из заданного списка). А [значение для name вытаскивается не из тега <name></name>, а из параметра name="&#x426;&#x432;&#x435;&#x442;". Как я понял последнее встретевшееся.

Comment: *id и parentId как вытаскивать из таких XML-ов?* `ROWS IDENTIFIED BY 'category'`